# Posterior probability for $\theta$ with a discrete prior

Tags: probability, bayesian, prior, posterior, exponential-distribution

I'm trying to find a posterior probability for this model but I can't find the solution. Help would be appreciated!

Prior distribution: $\theta$ follows a discrete probability function: $\mathbb{P}(\theta=d)=0.8=1-\mathbb{P}(\theta=3d)$. $d>0$ is a constant.

I have a sample of 6 exponential random variables ($X_i|\theta \sim$ Exponential($\theta$)). I know that $X_1<d,...,X_5<d$ and $X_6>d$. The $X_i$s are i.i.d.

I want to find the posterior probability $\mathbb{P}(X_7>d|X_1<d,...,X_5<d,X_6>d)$. Here's what I've done:

$\mathbb{P}(X_7>d|X_1<d,...,X_5<d,X_6>d)\\=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{P}(X_7>d|X_1<d,...,X_5<d,X_6>d, \theta))\\=\mathbb{E}(e^{-d/\theta})\\=e^{-1}\mathbb{P}(\theta=d|X_1<d,...,X_5<d,X_6>d)+e^{-1/3}(1-\mathbb{P}(\theta=d|X_1<d,...,X_5<d,X_6>d))\\=(e^{-1}-e^{-1/3})\mathbb{P}(\theta=d|X_1<d,...,X_5<d,X_6>d)+e^{-1/3}$

But I'm stuck here because I can't find an expression for $\mathbb{P}(\theta=d|X_1<d,...,X_5<d,X_6>d)$ that doesn't involve $d$.

Comment: Hint: assuming $\theta$ is a *scale* parameter, the value of $d$ doesn't matter.  Simply express all values in units where $d=1.$  If $\theta$ is a *rate* parameter, your work gets harder.  Which is it?

Comment: $\theta$ is a scale parameter here.

Answer (score 5):

It pays to start from first principles:
\begin{align}
\theta=\begin{cases}d&\text{with probability}\ 0.8\\
3d&\text{with probability}\ 0.2\end{cases}\tag{prior}\\
\mathbb{P}(\underbrace{X_1<d,...,X_5<d,X_6>d}_\text{observation}|\theta)&=e^{-5d/\theta}\left(1-e^{-d/\theta}\right)\tag{likelihood}
\end{align}
leading to
$$
\theta=\begin{cases}d&\text{with probability}\ 0.8\,e^{-5}(1-e^{-1})\big/\mathfrak Z\\
3d&\text{with probability}\ 0.2\,e^{-5/3}(1-e^{-1/3})\big/\mathfrak Z\\\end{cases}\tag{posterior}
$$
with
$$
\mathfrak Z=0.8\,e^{-5}(1-e^{-1})+0.2\,e^{-5/3}(1-e^{-1/3})
$$
the normalising constant. The predictive for the event $X_7>d$ is then
\begin{align}&\mathbb E\left[1-e^{-d/\theta}\big|X_1<d,...,X_5<d,X_6>d\right]\\&=\left[1-e^{-d/d}\right]0.8\,e^{-5}(1-e^{-1})\big/\mathfrak Z
+\left[1-e^{-d/3d}\right]0.2\,e^{-5/3}(1-e^{-1/3})\big/\mathfrak Z\\
&=0.8\,e^{-5}(1-e^{-1})^2\big/\mathfrak Z+0.2\,e^{-5/3}(1-e^{-1/3})^2\big/\mathfrak Z
\end{align}
which does not depend on $d$.